# extjs reuse object

Tags: extjs

If I had:

```
var x  = new Ext.form.formPanel({
});
```

I wanted to reuse in two places, e.g.:

```
var panel1 = new Ext.panel({ items:[x] });
var panel2 = new Ext.panel({ items:[x] });
```

Have try method `Ext.extend` but it did not work. If I do that it only renders one time on the page.

Answer (score 1):

Two Ext.form.FormPanel objects need to be created so you would have to do something similar to what's shown below:

```
var x  = new Ext.form.FormPanel({
});

var y  = new Ext.form.FormPanel({
});

var panel1 = new Ext.Panel({ items:[x] });
var panel2 = new Ext.Panel({ items:[y] });
```

Answer (score 1):

you can create your own formPanel class and then create this every time you want

```
MyForm = Ext.extend(Ext.form.FormPanel, {
  title: 'My Personal Form',
  width: 400,
  height: 250,
  padding: 10,
  initComponent: function() {
    this.items = [
        {
            xtype: 'textarea',
            anchor: '100%',
            fieldLabel: 'Label'
        },
        {
            xtype: 'textfield',
            fieldLabel: 'Label',
            anchor: '100%'
        }
    ];
    MyForm.superclass.initComponent.call(this);
  }
});

var panel1 = new Ext.panel(new MyForm({id:'test1'}));
var panel2 = new Ext.panel(new MyForm());
```

I insert in the first panel a id property, but you can insert anything else.
You can also change the standard configuration of your form overwriting the configuration